# Cannot find resource to load in dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I'm trying to load a xaml file inside a `ResourceDictionary` what I did is create a Dictionary like this:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
```

and then:

```
dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Resources\\Languages\\en-EN.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

now I've the following application folders structure:

```
AppName
    Resources
         Languages
               en-EN.xaml 
               it-IT.xaml
```

unfortunately I get this error:

> cannot find the resource 'resources/languages/en-en.xaml'

but the resource exist, why happen this?

Comment: Did you set build action on `en-EN.xaml` to "Embed Resource"?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight uhm nope, what is it?

Comment: In Visual Studio project right-click the `en-EN.xaml` file, and choose "Properties". In the "Properties" panel that opens on the right look up "Build Action" and set it to "Embed Resource" from the drop-down. Rebuild and run your project again.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight okay, I did this steps but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a pack URI:

```
dict.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Languages/en-EN.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

And keep the Build Action property set to its default value of **Page**.

If the resource dictionary is located in another assembly you also need to add a reference to this assembly and specify the name of it in the pack URI:

```
dict.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TheNameOfTheAssembly;component/Resources/Languages/en-EN.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: Is "en-EN.xaml" actually a resource dictionary then?

Comment: yes, but I guess that maybe the problem is 'cause I start the application (that load the dictionary) from another app, so essentially the code `new Uri()` try to find the dictionary inside the app that has started the second app (the one that load the dictionary). Infact I tried to create the same folder in the application (that start the second app), and I get no error. This is very strange. Notice that both project are inside the same solution.

Comment: You need to add a reference the project where the resource dictionary is defined for you to be able to include it in your app. And if it is located in another assembly you should also specify the name of this assembly. I edited my answer to clarify this.